# Selecting string elements in a list using integer elements from another list

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

I'm going to use an example to explain my question because I'm not sure the best way to put it into words.

Lets say I have two lists `a` and `b`:

`a = ["car", "bike", "train"]` and `b = [1, 3]`

And I want to create a new list `c` by selecting the items in `a` whose positions correspond to the integers in `b`, so list `c = ["car", "train"]`

How would I do this in Haskell? I think I have to use list comprehension but am unsure how. Cheers.

Comment: Is `b` guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *straightfoward* way to do this is using the [`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) operator that, for a given list and **zero-based** index, gives the *i*-th element.

So you could do this with the following list comprehension:

```
filterIndex :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
filterIndex a b = [a!!(i-1) | i <- b]
```

However this is **not efficient** since `(!!)` runs in *O(k)* with *k* the index. Usually if you work with **lists** you try to prevent looking up the *i*-th index.

---

In case it is **guaranteed that `b` is sorted**, you can make it more efficient with:

```
-- Only if b is guaranteed to be sorted
filterIndex = filterIndex' 1
    where filterIndex' _ _     [] = []
          filterIndex' i a:as2 js@(j:js2)  | i == j = a : tl js2
                                           | otherwise = tl js
                                           where tl = filterIndex' (i+1) as2
```

Or even more efficient:

```
-- Only if b is guaranteed to be sorted
filterIndex = filterIndex' 1
    where filterIndex' i l (j:js) | (a:as) <- drop (j-i) l = a : filterIndex' (j+1) as (js)
          filterIndex' _ _ [] = []
```

Comment: In your last example, are you using a guard to avoid a nested where clause?

Comment: Well that was not the intend, but it is indeed a nice side effect: it is a pattern guard. Such that if somehow the drop results in an empty list `[]` we know something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you're using `b = [0, 2]` instead (lists are 0 indexed in Haskell).

You can use a fold to build the new list:

```
selectIndices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
selectIndices as is = foldr (\i bs -> as !! i : bs) [] is
```

This starts with an empty list and adds new elements by selecting them from the list of `as` using an index `i` from the list of indices `is`.

More advanced: if you prefer a *point-free* style, the same function can be written:

```
selectIndices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
selectIndices as = foldr ((:) . (as !!)) []
```

Another approach which could be more efficient if the indices are sorted would be to go through the list one element at a time while keeping track of the current index:

```
selectIndices :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
selectIndices as is = go as 0 (sort is)
  where
    go :: [a] -> Int -> [Int] -> [a]
    go [] _ _  = []
    go _  _ [] = []
    go (a:as) n (i:is)
      | n == i    = a : go as (n + 1) is
      | otherwise = go as (n + 1) (i:is)
```

Comment: Note that it is easy to work with one-based indices by using `i-1`. But +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is tagging the values in `a` with the indices and then filtering according to the indices:

```
filterIndex :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
filterIndex b = fmap snd . filter (\(i, _) -> i `elem` b) . zip [1..]
-- non-point-free version:
-- filterIndex b a = fmap snd (filter (\(i, _) -> i `elem` b) (zip [1..] a))
```

(If you want zero-based rather than one-based indexing, just change the infinite list to `[0..]`. You can even parameterise it with something like `[initial..]`.)

If you need to make this more efficient, you might consider, among other things, a filtering algorithm that exploits ordering in `b` (cf. the answers by [Boomerang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43035337/2751851) and [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43035374/2751851)), and building a [dictionary](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) from the `zip [1..] a` list of pairs.